# flash drive 3.0 not detected on 2.0 usb port

Tags: usb

I bought a flash disk 3.0 but Ubuntu does not recognize it on usb 2.0 port

Is there a solution without buying an adapter?

Answer (score 1):

No. You need a USB 3.0 port to use it as a USB 3.0 device. You can still use it at USB 2.0 speeds.